# How to create one dictonary using 3 lists

Tags: python

I am new to Python and need help creating one dictionary file using three lists.

example:

```
list 1 = ["private", "private"]
list 2 = ["10.1.1.1", "10.11.11.11"]
list3 = [ "sfc", "gfc"]
```

my code:

```
dict = {}

for s in range(len(list1)):
       dict[list1[s]] =  {list2[s]: list3[s]}
print(dict)
```

I am getting output as `{'private': {'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}}`

but I want output as `{'private': {'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfx'}}`

Could somebody help me on how to get in this format?

Comment: Your expected output can't be represented as a python dictionary. Should it be like this? `{'private': [{'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfx'}]}` So a list of dictionaries?

Comment: What do you want the value associated with "private" to be? A list? A tuple? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = ["private", "private"]
list2 = ["10.1.1.1", "10.11.11.11"]
list3 = ["sfc", "gfc"]

my_dict = {}

for s in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[s] not in my_dict:
        my_dict[list1[s]] = []
    my_dict[list1[s]].append({list2[s]: list3[s]})

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'private': [{'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfc'}]}
```

It checks for element with same name basically key if present instead of overwriting it appends and update the old one

To get the output for Outer key, Inner key and value:

```
my_dict = {'private': [{'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfc'}]}

for key, value_list in my_dict.items():
    for value_dict in value_list:
        for inner_key, inner_value in value_dict.items():
            print(f"Outer Key: {key}, Inner Key: {inner_key}, Value: {inner_value}")
```

Output:

```
Outer Key: private, Inner Key: 10.1.1.1, Value: sfc
Outer Key: private, Inner Key: 10.11.11.11, Value: gfc
```

Please change it as per your need

Comment: And  i want to fetch the key and value from the output and from value I just want to get IP and name 

example : private, 
Ip = 10.1.1.1 
name : sfc

from my dict {'private': [{'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfc'}]}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
        print(key)
        print(value[0])

Comment: can you give example how you want it. @shivram. I have added basic structure please change to suit your need.

Comment: Can we add one list to the same dictionary? 

example :  list4 = ["11.1.1.1", "12.11.11.11"]
                  list 5 = ["llc" , ",mmc"]

now I want output as below 

{'private': [{'10.1.1.1','11.1.1.1': 'sfc','llc'}, {'10.1.1.1','12.1.1.1': 'sfc','mmc'} {'10.11.11.11',11.1.1.1': 'gfc','llc'},{'10.11.11.11',1121.1.1': 'gfc','mmc'} ]}

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function.

Right now, you overwrite the `dict[list1[s]]` but you want to not replace it but add to it. `setdefault` allows you to only replace the value if it does not yet exist.

```
# consider giving your variables proper names, I'm not exactly sure what they should be named though
scopes = ["private", "private"]
ips = ["10.1.1.1", "10.11.11.11"]
kinds = [ "sfc", "gfc"]

# dict is a built in type, avoid naming a variable the same
out = {}
# Use zip instead of `range(len())` when possible, it's better style and more compact
for scope, ip, kind in zip(scopes, ips, kinds):
    # set default assigns to `{}` to out[scope] if it does not exist
    out.setdefault(scope, {})[ip]=kind

print(out)
```

Output:

```py
{'private': {'10.1.1.1': 'sfc', '10.11.11.11': 'gfc'}}
```

[Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU9BCsJADLzvK0JPLdRibyL0JdJDaXc1KLuhmwpa-hIvvehT_IO_cdOtJoGEzAzJPF5045Oz8_wc2Gx2n7dvHWkPFRwS6vHasE5y-I-1QopguS1KSUFlLmMFxhltt3Ag8aYV_BharZQbOKzHSRnXw3InB6QcRABo4Y6UxvOy9xHw2V5BiCAuvOZOm2a4cLrKxyk7INWVMJUKX1pOAzOLblZTP3Nf)

[See also docs for the zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the values to be a list then:

```
list_1 = ["private", "private"]
list_2 = ["10.1.1.1", "10.11.11.11"]
list_3 = ["sfc", "gfc"]

output = dict()

for a, b, c in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
    output.setdefault(a, []).append({b: c})

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
{'private': [{'10.1.1.1': 'sfc'}, {'10.11.11.11': 'gfc'}]}
```